# Spring Boot - Application failed to start with classpath

Tags: spring, tomcat, war, spring-boot

What a nice day, isn't it?

I hope that someone of this community can help me.

**Tomcat Version 7,
Servlet API 3.0**

I like to start my **Spring Boot** project in a tomcat using a .war. Heres my code of the spring boot application:

**Main-Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.###.dashboard")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.###.dashboard.domain")
public class Dashboard extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Object[] {Dashboard.class}, args);    
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Dashboard.class);
    }


}
```

**pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.###.dashboard</groupId>
  <artifactId>Dashboard</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Dashboard</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

     <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mobile</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.###.dashboard.main.Dashboard</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**error message of tomcat/spring boot**

```
2014-12-04 13:32:18.878  INFO 198588 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start
with classpath: [file:/../tomcat7/webapps/dashboard/WEB-INF/classes/, ..path to libs, list of all jar files in folder libs..
2014-12-04 13:32:19.091  INFO 198588 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.
boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@61f0fe81: startup date [Thu Dec 04 13:32:15 CET 2014]; root of
 context hierarchy
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Where i need to set the classpath? I thought i dont need to set any .xml-files.

Thank you!

Comment: **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space** - you need to assign more memory to JVM running Tomcat. Search for this error and I am sure you will find the answer

Answer (score -2):

One of the reasons behind this error is that the port has already been assigned to others. You can test it by changing port address. Simply add a application.propeties under resource directory. And then add the following content 
server.port: 9000 // you can write any port you want